# How to join input value from different input field to one value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, blogger

I have problem with input value, I want to use it in blogger, as you know that form in blogger is inherited from contact-form, so I just can use value form like, name,email,and message, 
and in message form value I want to make it double with different value, but sending to admin email as one, join the value from input 1, and input 2.
maybe like using javascript?

```
<input id="ContactForm1_contact-form-name" name="name" placeholder="Name" size="20" required="" type="text"/>

<input id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" type="email"/>

<input id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message" name="email-message" placeholder="input 1" size="20" type="text"/>

<input id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message" name="email-message" placeholder="input 2" size="20" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Use `concat()` or `+` to join string values in JS, to read values from field see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field